# Convert date and time to ISO yyyy-mm-dd in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a csv file which I have opened in Excel date is formated like "2014-08-28 09:03:19.789".

How can the above be converted to just yyyy-mm-dd (2014-08-28) in Excel?

I have tried to set the column to yyyy-mm-dd but it does not change.

Comment: If it does not automatically change to a date then it is text that looks like a date.  In an empty column try `=DATEVALUE(A1)`.  Where A1 is the first cell with the date.  Then format that cell `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Strange does not work either just say `#Name?`

Comment: When you widen the column, is the `2014-08-28 09:03:19.789` right-aligned or left-aligned. Right-aligned is a true date; left-aligned is text. Does the fx bar show something different than what is displayed in the cell? Typically, that date-time would not be the same in the fx bar if the datetime was a true datetime and not text-that-looks-like-a-date. Is your system under a DMY or MDY regional setting? How many are there? Are some OK and some not?

Comment: funny thing is when I copy and pasted you example date, my system automatically detected it as a proper date time and converted it on me.  I had to take special steps to keep it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Excel are you using?  (I'm not sure if that matters.)

If you tried just typing `yyyy-mm-dd` in the format selector box that will not work.

[image]

You need to open the custom format dialog and type in `yyyy-mm-dd` as a new format there.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013. I have tried the above as well with no success.

Comment: I think Excel does not support milliseconds.

Comment: You could try `=VALUE(LEFT(myDate, 10))`.  This formula will grab the first 10 chars as text (the date without the time), then you can format that with a normal format string.

Comment: @JamesFaix Excel supports milliseconds:  `hh:mm:ss.000` is a valid format.

Comment: Maybe using year through milliseconds is too many significant digits for Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Text to Columns` wizard either on the worksheet cell, or by `Importing` the file using the Data Ribbon ► Get External Data tab ► From text.

For that column, select `Space` as the delimiter and, at Step 3, YMD for the format.  When you are finished, custom format the date column and the time columns as you wish.

If you need the entire date/time stamp in the same cell, add them together in a third column, and format as needed.

Comment: Problem with this is that the file contain 5 different columns with various dates and the file has a total of 105 000 rows. As I belive I will continue getting the file in this format I need to have a somehow easier approach.

Comment: @Andy Most likely a VBA macro to do the Import and parsing would be your best bet.  If you are not familiar with VBA, you could start by using the macro recorder.  I am surprised, however, that your date/time strings do not automatically convert to real excel dates that you can just custom format how you want.  Something different about your source file or your environment might explain that.  But without real data that reproduces the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work regardless of your system settings and is based on your date time value really being a string once its been imported into excel.  This solution will assume your date is in A1

First strip out the year:

```
=left(A1,4)
```

Then strip out the month:

```
=mid(A1,6,2)
```

Then strip out the day:

```
=trim(mid(A1,9,2))
```

note if you know you have a leading zero in from of single digit days then y ou can drop the trim function.

Now you date can be convert to an excel format date using the date function and substituting in the information pull out above.

```
=Date(left(A1,4),mid(A1,6,2),trim(mid(A1,9,2)))
```

If your cell is not formatted correctly you will probably get an integer like 420303 or something to that effect  Its the number of days since January 0, 1900 on a windows OS, something like since 1904 on a Mac.

So for the time you repeat the process, but I am going to suggest you try option A) first and if it does not work for you try option B)

### Option A) for time shortcut

```
If you time also show trailing 0 ie 9.000 for seconds then you might get away with:

=Timevalue(right(A1,12))
```

Now if that does not work for you we can adjust the 12 to be:

```
LEN(A1)-Find(" ",A1)
```

Now if option A and using time value does not work for you then we need to go in and rip out the hours minutes and seconds and essentially do the same process that was done for the date as described above.

### Option B) ripped by units

To get the hours use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2)
```

To get the minutes use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2)
```

To get seconds use

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)+3)
```

This assumes you have a leading 0 for single digit seconds 0-9.

Now you can take all that and drop it into the TIME formula to get the following

```
=TIME(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2),MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)+3))
```

Now since days at the integers and time is saved as the decimal value, we can combine the date and time formula with a + and you should now have the whole thing ready to have formatting applied to it.

```
=Date(left(A1,4),mid(A1,6,2),trim(mid(A1,9,2)))+TIME(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2),MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)+3))
```